# Find the line of intersection between two planes.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

> Consider the planes:
>
> $$\begin{eqnarray}x + y + 2z = 1\\
> −x + 2y + z = 5\end{eqnarray}$$
>
> 1. Find the angle between the two planes.
> 2. Find the line of intersection of the two planes.

I was able to answer part (1), and I found that the angle was $60$ degrees ($\pi/3$ radians). The part that I'm having trouble with is finding the line of intersection of the two planes. I have no idea where to start, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding both equations we get
$$3y+3z=6$$ or $$y=2-z$$ substituting $z=t$ we obtain
$$y=2-t$$ and $$x=2-t+2t=1$$ gives us $$x=-1-t$$
So our line has the equation
$$[x,y,z]=[-1,2,0]+t[-1,-1,1]$$ where $t$ is a real number.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only part I don't understand is how you came up with the second last line. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @N_Mathematics_B The usual method for this question: let one of the variables be a "parameter" (that you can rename $t$), then solve the system for the other two variables: you get a parametric equation of the line. Here $z$ is the parameter, so the parametric equation is $(x=f(t), y=g(t), z=t)$, with linear functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, the normal vectors to the planes are:

- $n_1=(1,1,2)$
- $n_2=(-1,2,1)$

then a direction vector for the line is

$$n_1 \wedge n_2 = (-3,-3,3)$$

Comment: +1 Interestingly, normal vectors also give very easily an answer to the first question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, that's a very good point!